# Express refresh_token error with React frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, asynchronous, async-await

I have a React app with a Expressjs backend.

To log requests, I have two middlewares. Below is the code for both of them.

```
morgan.token("status-text", (_req, res) => res.statusMessage)

const morganMiddlewareRequest = morgan(
  "Started :method :url for :remote-addr",
  {
    stream: { write: (message) => logger.http(message.trim()) },
    immediate: true,
  }
)

const morganMiddlewareResponse = morgan(
  "Completed :status :status-text in :response-time ms.",
  {
    stream: { write: (message) => logger.http(message) },
  }
)
```

The output is the following:

```
[2023-01-25 01:24:36] Started GET /api/users for ::1
[2023-01-25 01:24:36] Completed 200 OK in 4.707 ms.
```

When I log in, the client stores the access_token and the refresh_token in the local storage, and for every request the client send the access_token in Headers. To refresh my access_token when it expires I use axios interceptors in order to request a new pair of {access_token, refresh_token}. If my access_token is expired, I just send a POST request to 'auth/refresh_token' to get a new pair of tokens. Both tokens are sent to headers.

Below is the code of the axios interceptor

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(async function (config) {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken")
  if (token) {
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token)
    if (Date.now() >= decoded.exp * 1000) {
      const axiosRefreshToken = axios.create({})
      await axiosRefreshToken
        .post(
          "http://localhost:3000/auth/refresh_token",
          {},
          { headers: { token: localStorage.getItem("refreshToken") } }
        )
        .then(function (response) {
          const data = response.data.data
          localStorage.setItem("accessToken", data.accessToken)
          localStorage.setItem("refreshToken", data.refreshToken)
          config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(
            "accessToken"
          )}`
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error)
        })
    }
    config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem(
      "accessToken"
    )}`
  }
  return config
})
```

Everything works fine until I'm trying to 'overkill' it. When I'm logged in and I refresh multiple times on the home page (on the home page I fetch data from backend), the backend request seems to not be executed correctly. This happens when refresh_token request is somehow sent twice at the same time(same minute, second ...). The output of the logger is the following one:

```
[2023-01-25 01:04:30] Started POST /auth/refresh_token for ::1
[2023-01-25 01:04:30] {}
[2023-01-25 01:04:30] refreshtokens.findOneAndDelete(does not matter)
[2023-01-25 01:04:30] Completed - - in - ms. (HERE IS THE PROBLEM)
[2023-01-25 01:04:30] refreshtokens.insertOne(does not matter)
[2023-01-25 01:04:30] Started POST /auth/refresh_token for ::1
[2023-01-25 01:04:30] {}
[2023-01-25 01:04:30] refreshtokens.findOneAndDelete(does not matter)
[2023-01-25 01:04:30] Completed 200 OK in 4.050 ms.
```

Note that in auth/refresh_token I delete the old token and add the new one to db.

As you can see, on the 4th row, my :status and :status-text and :response time are "-". I can't understand why this is happening.
This is auth/refresh_token

```
exports.refreshToken = async (req, res) => {
  const requestErrors = validate(req)
  if (!requestErrors.isEmpty()) return 
    res.error(requestErrors.array()[0])
  const refreshToken = req.headers.token
  const dbToken = await RefreshToken.findOneAndDelete({ token: 
    refreshToken })
  if (!dbToken) return res.error({ error: "Invalid Token" })

  const payload = { id: dbToken.user }
  const newAccessToken = jwt.generateToken(payload, "access")
  const newRefreshToken = jwt.generateToken(payload, "refresh")
  const token = new RefreshToken({
    token: newRefreshToken,
    user: dbToken.user,
  })
  await token.save()

  return res.success({
    accessToken: newAccessToken,
    refreshToken: newRefreshToken,
  })
}
```

I was thinking to add some wait time before sending the request, but I don't think this should be the solution. What can I do?

Comment: How about implementing an abortController to abort/cancel your request when you make a new request behind ?

Comment: What is an AbortController? And how should I use that?
The idea sounds good tho.

Comment: Well I didn't use Axios yet, but you can have a look on their documentation since you re using Axios : https://axios-http.com/docs/cancellation

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and come with response.

Comment: I could not solve this using AbortController..